# Clamp for tight quarters

Tags: tools, hand-tools

Is there a kind of clamp whose one pressing arm (or whatever you call it) is a simple straight bracket perpendicular to the clamping motion line (purple below) while the other is regular (black below)?

[image]

<sub>Sorry for the terrible illustration.</sub>

Comment: You might get more/better answers if you described the problem you are trying to solve, rather than one specific approach to solving it.

Comment: Please add dimensions (sizes) to the drawing, and tell us how much pressure you need. If you are only strapping an inch or three (not very tightly), perhaps an one hole strap and an right angle bracket would be effective.

Comment: Your drawing is unclear: what is clamp and what is the workpiece(s)?